# Configure multiple Email Senders for scheduled Jasper Reports

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jasperserver

I have several reports running on a schedule on my Jasper Server, however I want to be able to configure the email scheduler to be able to send from a different Email Address for each Report.

When I look at the js.quartz.properties file I only see one configurable email address line

```
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=yourname@yourdomain.com
```

Is it possible to schedule one report to be sent from one email address and the other to be sent from a different email address?

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible by customizing the product, but not configurable, unfortunately.